# Sublime Text 2 (or other) syntax highlighter for NetLogo

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, netlogo

Does anyone know of a syntax highlighter, ideally for Sublime Text 2, for NetLogo?  I'd rather not write my code directly in NetLogo and prefer to use editors I'm more used to, but I can't seem to find a syntax highlighter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [NetLogo syntax on PackageControl.io](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NetLogo%20Syntax).

Also, as you see can see on the [NetLogo resources page](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml), there is [one for VIM](http://voo-du.net/media/dump/nlogo.vim) and [one for BBEdit](http://protist.biology.washington.edu/netlogo/bbedit-CLM/). There is also a [plugin for Pygments](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netlogo-pygment/).

If you ever want to try rolling your own or improve another, this [NetLogo wiki page](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Syntax-highlighting) might be useful.

Comment: Atom and VS Code plugins are also available: https://atom.io/packages/language-netlogo and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akashrajkn.language-netlogo-code

Answer (score 0):

There is one floating around for notepad++.
I downloaded it a while ago, but I can't seem to find the link for you right now. Someone posted it in yahoo groups, and it is a user defined language you have to import into Notepad ++. I wish I had the link for you, I'm sorry I can't be of more help.